# how to show different dropdown lists from different columns of a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to show data of different columns by different dropdownlists. Each dropdown list will show data of different table. This is my script but it shows all data in only one dropdownlist.

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or
die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');
mysql_select_db('mobiledb', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>rest</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="commit.php method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Movie Type</td>
<td><select name="movie_type">
<?php
$query = 'SELECT 
       customer_id, customer_name, customer_address, customer_order
      FROM
         customers';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
 echo '<option value="' . $row['customer_id'] . '"> ' . $row['customer_name'] .  '</option>';
echo '<option value="' . $row['customer_id'] . '"> ' . $row['customer_address'] .  '</option>';
echo '<option value="' . $row['customer_id'] . '"> ' . $row['customer_order'] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question again and again](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2602526/vick?tab=questions).

Comment: If I understood correctly I think you can remove the echo () and replace it with a variable. like $box1 .= "<optio... $box2 = "<option.. then just echo it

Comment: SELECT customer_id, WHERE what? seems like you should try to echo `$row['customer_id']` to see whats in there instead of runnin loops, you are taking steps way to big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood, this is a basic html syntax:

you are getting

```
<select>
    <option value="...."> customer name</option> 
    <option value="...."> customer address</option> 
    <option value="...."> customer order</option> 
    ...
</select>
```

and you want

```
<select>
    <option value="...."> customer name</option> 
    ...
</select>

<select>
    <option value="...."> customer address</option> 
    ...
</select>

<select>
    <option value="...."> customer order</option> 
    ...
</select>
```

for 3 different dropdown lists, tou need 3 different select
your code generate 3 different echo into the same `select` element
(into the same `td`)